# WPF DataGrid Binding property not found

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have just started using WPF and I am facing a problem displaying data to a DataGrid.

**WPF (Views\ResultsPage.xaml):**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgResults"
          Margin="2"
          Style="{DynamicResource AzureDataGrid}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding SampleData}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"
          TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Well" Binding="{Binding WellID}"/>
      ..
```

**C# (Data\SampleData.cs):**

```
public class : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _wellID;

    public string WellID
    {
        get
        {
            return _wellID;
        }
        set
        {
            _wellID = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("WellID");
        }
    }
  ...

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**I get this error:** System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'SampleData'

Comment: You need to create a new instances of `SampleData` and then bind that instances as a `List` or `ObservableCollection` to your `DataGrid`.

Comment: SampleData should be a property in your ViewModel like this: `ObservableCollection<SampleData> SampleData {get;set;}` and don't forget about `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: Have you set the DataContext of your Window? Otherwise your XAML assumes, that your Data comes from CodeBehind.

Comment: I have updated the code with INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 0):

`SampleData` is supposed to be a property of the `DataContext` of the `DataGrid` (or a parent element) that returns an `IEnumerable<SampleData>`. Try this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    //set the DataContext of the window itself or the DataGrid
        dgResults.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        SampleData = new List<SampleData>();
        SampleData.Add(new SampleData() { WellID = "1" });
        SampleData.Add(new SampleData() { WellID = "2" });
    }

    public List<SampleData> SampleData { get; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You meant `List<SampleData> sd = new List<SampleData>();` ??

Comment: Sorry, I had an error with `SampleData.Add`, that I resolved using `List<SampleData> list = SampleData.ToList();` before that. However my DataGrid is empty, I think that it cannot resolve SampleData because is a class placed in another folder

Comment: Yes I am using your code. I have just changed this `SampleData = new List<SampleData>();
                List<SampleData> list = SampleData.ToList();
                list.Add(new SampleData() { WellID = "1" });` because I get an error with the Add method

Comment: You need to set the SampleData *property*. It's this one that you bind to in the view. And my sample code works as-is- There is no reason to call ToList() on a list...

Comment: Apologies, I see you are an expert of WPF. As I said I have just moved from Windows Form to WPF. Using your code I get "IEnumerable<SampleData> does not contain Add definition".

Comment: Just change the type of property from IEnumerable<SampleData> to List<SampleData> then. See my edit.

Comment: I managed to display the data using ItemsSource instead DataContext. Too many ways to insert data imho.. Anyway many thanks for your help.

Comment: By setting the ItemsSource property programmatically? That's not MVVM.

Comment: I do want to learn the proper way, but currently I am not able to get the results. Following your instructions a get an empty DataGrid.

Comment: You obviously haven't followed my suggestion then. Try to copy and paste my sample code into a new window.